# Pandas read_csv creating trailing unnamed columns and not read in entire csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I found some similar questions here but None of them solved my problem. 
I have a csv file with one column containing some long strings, and the other columns with some short strings. When I read it in with

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

I got:

```
text    colA     colB    colC   colD      Unnamed: 5    Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  Unnamed: 10
```

But I only have `text   colA     colB    colC   colD` these columns in the csv file.

I thought it was fine I can just remove those unnamed columns, but I found that I got `df.shape` is `(180106, 11)`\
However, My csv file is about 270000 rows.
I don't know if these two issues are related to each other.

I tried to add an option `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` in read_csv
This gives me:

```
b'Skipping line 17: expected 11 fields, saw 12\nSkipping line 18: expected 11 fields, saw 12\nSkipping line 19: expected 11 fields, saw 12\
```

This skips even more lines, making it even fewer rows than 180106

I think this maybe related to how CSV file is parsed but I don't know how I can read it fully. And sorry the data in the CSV file is sensitive so I can't share a sample.

Comment: Your `text` field might have commas in it. In this case, this field should be quoted in order to be correctly parsed.

Comment: @foglerit but I do see a lot of the rows where the text columns contains comma parsed correctly in the dataframe

Comment: You should provide an example of your csv; just enough to reproduce the problem - [mre].

Answer (score 0):

just bring the csv file to the filename where you are working

```
df=pd.read_csv("file_name")
df.isnull().sum()
df.describe()
df.info()
```

*by is null you can get the sum of true value of all data columns*
*by using descrbive you get statistic description of data*
*by using info you get all data detail*
*if none of them shown the data information delate the data and download again*